# Upload markers with coordinates to Firebase and show them to other users on React Native app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developing a crime map using Firebase + React Native.
I would like to save on Firebase the coordinates of the marker generated by the user once he/she touches the map (including other fields such as crime type, details, etc.)
So once the markers are saved onto Firebase, I would like to show them to other users on the same map, also displaying the previously mentioned fields as information.

[image: These are the markers shown as user taps on map]

Is this possible? If so, what is the best way to achieve this?
Users back-end has been implemented, including react-native-maps library for google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have  2 categories of users:

1. GROUP A USERS: Reporting crimes with information includes crime scene location coordinates.
2. GROUP B USERS: Monitoring reported crimes with instant updates of the crime scene on the map.

With Firebase'Firestore, create a `collection` named `crimes`, where the app adds new reported crimes reported by GROUP A USER as a `document`.

Each crime `document` must contain coordinates of the location of the crime scene.`react-native-maps` has `onPress` event props which return coordinates on the map where the user taps.

crime's `document` should look like :

```
const crime = {
type:"CRIME_TYPE",
coordinates:{
longitude:30,0988,
latitude:-1.98777,
//... more details
}
```

Add this document when the user reports a crime

```
// Define reported crime document information
const crime = {
type:"CRIME_TYPE",
coordinates:{
longitude:30,0988,
latitude:-1.98777,
}
//... more details
}


// Firestore crimes collection reference
const  crimesRef  = firestore.collection('crimes')

// add new reported crime document in collection
crimesRef.add(crime)
```

At this stage, the user has reported (submitted) a crime. We need to notify GROUP B USERS  about the new reported crime.

GROUP B USERS should subscribe to the `crimes` collection especially when a new document is added.

```
firestore.collection("crimes")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New reported crime: ", change.doc.data());
                // add logic to update map with new reported crime data

            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified crime : ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed crime: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

I didn't cover all implementation details, this's only a brief overview.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Would you mind if I can share you a progress update of this app in a near future? I would like to try implementing this answer.

Comment: Yes, feel free to get in touch with me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com